# Incompatibility issues between OpenCV and GTK+ 3

Tags: python, opencv, gtk, gtk3

I am developing a real-time screen-capturing program using `Python 3.10.4` with `OpenCV` and `GTK+ 3`. I ran into an issue I cannot solve - `GTK+ 3` seems to be incompatible with `OpenCV`. To give a bit more context to my problem, I am using `GTK+ 3` to capture each frame from any selected window (minimized or not) using `GdkPixbuf` and I am using `OpenCV` to efficiently process and show each captured frame in real-time.

Here's the issue. Consider the following simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

img = np.zeros((100,100,3))
cv2.imshow('test', img) # ERROR happens here
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The following code produces a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) (exit code 139, signal 11). The segmentation fault happens exactly when `cv2.imshow()` is called. If, however, I were to change `GTK` version to 2, by writting `gi.require_version("Gtk", "2.0")` or remove it altogether, the SIGSEGV does not occur. This is not a solution, since I need `GTK+ 3` at the very least.

So far, I tried downgrading `OpenCV`, but no other version worked. What I found to be working is `PyGTK` in place of `GTK+ 3`, but `PyGTK` is very old and depreciated - I do not want to use it.

How can I make `GTK+ 3` work with `OpenCV`? Is it even possible?

Comment: You seem to show a disregard for the `dtype` of your Numpy array `img` Try `img = np.zeros((100,100,3), np.uint8)`

Comment: Good point, I should have specified the type. Unfortunately, specifying the type does not solve the issue.

Comment: the dtype of that example array makes no difference. the array contains all zeros and imshow will just show it as black, as it should. -- use **GTK** for showing the image. make a GUI with GTK. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for GUIs. it can show images but that's a convenience function, nothing more. --  you can't use multiple types of GUI in the same program. perhaps OpenCV also tries to use GTK, but it didn't expect that some things are already initialized, and then you get a crash. so don't use imshow.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That's unfortunate. I am using OpenCV for computer vision as well. In particular, I am capturing real-time frames whilst performing OCR (text recognition) and then showing the results. I wanted to make it simple and not included this detail in my question. I really have no option but to use OpenCV. But GTK also provides very useful tools for capturing frames (even when windows are minimized). I failed to find something similar to GTK that would provide such functionality.

Comment: you don't have to resign from using `OpenCV` to capturing frames. You have to only skip `imshow()` and `waitKey` and use `GTK` to display frames

Comment: @furas Simple, yet good advice, thank you. Following your advice, I managed to get it to work by using `GTK` for displaying the captured frames. I guess my problem is solved.

Comment: uh, that's what I said though, use GTK... did I write too much other stuff?

Comment: Yes, I realise you said the same thing in a more concise way, plus more. I did read your comment a number of times and it was helpful, but for some reason, the idea only clicked in my brain after reading the other comment. It’s been a long day and I don’t know why my brain works that way. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.imshow` is probably not supposed to be used in GUIs, but for a quick-and-dirty solution see the following code (tested on gtk 3.42 @ python 3.10.1):

```py
import time
import threading
import cv2
import numpy

cv2.imshow('warmup', numpy.zeros((100,100,3)))
time.sleep(0.5)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

demo = Gtk.Window()
btn = Gtk.Button.new_with_label('Input test')
btn.connect('clicked', lambda _: print('Input works'))
demo.add(btn)

# Capturing from webcam here, but other sources will probably work too
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.open(0)

def cv2_loop():
  while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret: break

    cv2.imshow('capture', frame)

cv2_thread = threading.Thread(target=cv2_loop)
cv2_thread.start()

def done(*args):
  cap.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
  cv2_thread.join()
  Gtk.main_quit()

demo.connect('destroy', done)
demo.show_all()

Gtk.main()
cv2_thread.join()
```

The trick is to force-initialize OpenCV before you import GTK stuff.